# Hide custom tab WooCommerce (Grouped Product Pages) depending on Child Product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set up some custom tabs to display for grouped products.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_paym_product_tab' );

function woo_paym_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post;
    if( function_exists('get_product') ){
        $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        if( $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ){
            $tabs['paym-plans'] = array( 'title' => __( 'Contract Deals', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 10, 'callback' => 'woo_paym_product_tab_content' );
            return $tabs;
        } else {
        return $tabs;
        }
    }
}

function woo_paym_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content
    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}
```

How can I hide this tab depending on the Grouped Product > Child Products attribute. I only want this tab to show on the grouped product page if the child products contain an attribute 'PAYM'.

At the moment the tab is set to display for 'grouped' products only. I would also like to change this to 'grouped' products and certain category.

Comment: For the second bit, would this work? 
```if( $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) && $product->is_category('your_category'))```

Comment: And actually, for the first bit you should be able to just test for ```$product->get_attribute( 'PAYM' );```
But I haven't used wooCommerce in too long so I'm not confident to post that as an answer

Comment: @JohnCH (Reply to first comment) that doesn't work when I try that no tabs show at all not even the footer it breaks the site??

Comment: @JohnCH (Reply to second comment) The attribute is only visible in the child products. PAYM applies to children of the group only not the group itself. although i'm not 100% sure on weather it will also fetch the attributes of the child products, what do you think?

Comment: I have no idea for the first one, does it give you an error message? For the second you may need to do a ```$product->get_children()``` then use ```get_attribute('PAYM')``` on the child.

Comment: @JohnCH would that be `$product->get_children( $product->get_attribute( 'contract-type' ) == 'PAYM' ) )`

Comment: @JohnCH no error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103971/discussion-between-johnch-and-scott).

Comment: @JohnCH I have managed to hide the tab content if there are no products so the tab is now empty - how can I hide empty tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Following function will help you hide the tab for other product types.

```
// Show custom fields for grouped product.

function hide_custom_js() {

if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
    return;
endif;

?><script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        jQuery( '.your_custom _tab_class' ).addClass( 'show_if_grouped' ).show();
    });
</script><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'hide_custom_js' );
```

You must replace the `.your_custom _tab_class` class with your custom tab class.